# Run the same service with different parameters

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to run multiple services. Here is a short extract of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: backend
  backoffice:
    build: backend
    command: mycommand --parameter 1
```

What I'd like to do is to run the `backoffice` service multiple times, with different values for `--parameter`. I read about the `scale` command, but it doesn't seem to work like I'd like to.

Is there a way to do this without having to declare multiple services `backoffice1`, `backoffice2`, ...?

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: backend
  backoffice1:
    build: backend
    command: mycommand --parameter 1
  backoffice2:
    build: backend
    command: mycommand --parameter 2
  backoffice3:
    build: backend
    command: mycommand --parameter 3
```

Comment: what's wrong with running multiple services `backoffice1, backoffice2`?

Comment: @IvanKlymenchenko I'd like to avoid having a docker-compose.yml with 5000 lines of code... (I have much more than 3 parameters to run my services with)

Comment: (If you happened to be using Kubernetes, then there's a good [tag:kubernetes-helm] solution for this, but if you're on a single-host Compose setup now then Kubernetes is...an investment.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Unfortunately yes, I'm on a single-host deployment, but I'll look into this. Do you know if there's something similar with docker swarm?

Comment: The important thing about Helm specifically is that it runs a templating engine over your Kubernetes manifest files, so it's straightforward to make a family of related Deployments.  It's pretty intricately tied to specifically Kubernetes though.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work with `docker-compose run`.

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use `docker-compose run`. You can do something like this:

```
$ docker-compose run -d backoffice mycommand --parameter 1
$ docker-compose run -d backoffice mycommand --parameter 2
$ docker-compose run -d backoffice mycommand --parameter 3
```

However, a simpler way would be to modify your `docker-compose.yml` to use a custom entrypoint like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: backend
  backoffice:
    build: backend
    entrypoint: mycommand --parameter
```

Then you can just provide a parameter on each invocation of `docker-compose run` that will be executed by `mycommand`.

E.g:

```
$ docker-compose run -d backoffice 1
$ docker-compose run -d backoffice 2
$ docker-compose run -d backoffice 3
```